# How to PXE boot with the new Unified Image in 12.10?

Tags: live-cd, pxe

How do I setup a "live CD" PXE boot with the new Ubuntu 12.10 with the Unified Image (since netinstall package does not exist)?

Or the instructions [**here**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro)
still work?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you fixed this problem... you can use the following [Tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro) to start off.

very straight forward and easy to follow.